# unrecognized debugging option: 1 [enabled by default]

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-errors, makefile, cross-platform

I am writing a cross-platform gtk application for Windows and linux in C. Today I came across the strange compiler error in the title (which I have never seen before).

This happens when I build my program in Windows, but not in Linux. When I build it in Windows via command line, this message shows up as a warning and the program compiles successfully. However, when I build it in Code Blocks, this message shows up as an error and it does not compile.

Here is what is in my makefile:

```
ifeq ($(OS),Windows_NT)
    CC = mingw32-gcc
    BIN = "bin\"
    DIRCHK = if exist bin rd /s /q bin
    CPGLADE = copy main_win.glade bin\Release
    RM = rmdir /S /Q bin
    SQLITE = -dll sqlite3.dll
    DLL = copy /Y sqlite3.dll bin\Debug && copy /Y sqlite3.dll bin\Release
else
    CC = gcc
    BIN = -vp bin/
    RM = rm -rf bin
    SQLITE = -l sqlite3 -ldl -lpthread
    DLL = rm -f sqlite3.dll
endif

SHELL = bash

GTK := $(shell pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0)

CFLAGS := -g -Wall -static-libgcc -lm $(GTK) $(SQLITE)

TARGET = deans2

all:
    $(DIRCHK)
    mkdir $(BIN)Debug
    mkdir $(BIN)Release
    $(CPGLADE)
    $(CC) main.c $(CFLAGS) -o bin/Release/$(TARGET)
    $(DLL)

Debug:
    $(DIRCHK)
    mkdir $(BIN)Debug
    $(CPGLADE)
    $(CC) main.c $(CFLAGS) -o bin/Debug/$(TARGET)
    $(DLL)

Release:
    $(DIRCHK)
    mkdir $(BIN)Release
    $(CPGLADE)
    $(CC) main.c $(CFLAGS) -o bin/Release/$(TARGET)
    $(DLL)

clean:
    $(RM)
```

Comment: Show us the command line that generates the error.

Comment: Is the error perhaps `unrecognized debugging option: l` (the letter `l` not the number `1`)? Because `-dll` isn't a valid flag to `gcc` that I'm aware of and would cause that error I believe (from the value of `SQLITE` used in `CFLAGS` then in the `$(CC)` line when building on Windows).

Comment: @EtanReisner That seems to have done the trick. I'm not sure why I was using that flag before, but now I am building with the full amalgamation as specified in the SQLite documentation. Thanks and sorry for the dumb question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain the error was `unrecognized debugging option: 1`? (The number one.)

Was it perhaps `unrecognized debugging option: l`? (The letter ell.)

I would expect that latter error from the `-dll` flag set in `SQLITE` when building on Windows as that isn't a valid flag for `gcc` that I'm aware of.

What were you trying to do there?